# regex for finding a pattern between keywords and storing it in a group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the following information from the string in JavaScript.

**input string:**

```
?q=Diwali_s:BRAND|discount:60 - 70^70 - 80^80 - 90|Brand:Yo
Jelo&sort=plrty&MID=fashion_weekEndEOSS_womensFootwearYO
```

I need to extract the brand name `Yo Jelo` from the above string

```
Brand:([^\&\|])*[\&\|]
```

What I was thinking is:

Look for keyword `Brand:`, then store all the characters not matching `&` and `|` in a group and then finally detect if there is a `&` or `|` at the end. However, the group contains only the character `o` in it. Help me understand, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try with: `Brand:([^\&\|]+)*[\&\|]`

Comment: oops.. that was quite stupid of me to put the * outside. `Brand:([^\&\|]+)[\&\|]` is working fine. I should get some sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\bBrand:([^&|]+)
```

and grab captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU3gC3/1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JavaScript but your current regex was close but the first capture group did not contain the quantifier `*`.

```
Brand:([^\&\|]*)[\&\|]
```

Moving the asterisks into the capture group gave me the results I think you were looking for.

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/qY5uW5/1)

I'm sure that anubhava's answer is a great update to this as well.